# SIP UAC crash during a call

Tags: sip, voip

If a SIP UAC crashes in the middle of a SIP call, what is the expected behavior of the UAS and the remote UAC? Assume that a single UAS connects both UACs in the call.

Is this scenario discussed in a RFC/draft. If so can someone point me to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the core SIP standard ([RFC 3261](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt)) there is no requirement to check the other end of the call is still there and it's left up to implementors. In practise a user agent would typically detect there have been no RTP packets for a period (such as 60s) and hang up the call.

As with everything to do with every aspect of SIP there is an RFC extension that deals with SIP session timers ([RFC 4028](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4028.txt)) that documents a way to deal with session timeouts at the SIP level. Although because it's not in the core standard support for it will vary.

Comment: What is the UAS behavior in this case? Can you comment on both cases: (i) when Session timeout has been negotiated as per RFC 4028 and (ii) when there is no session timeout

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look at RTP stream. If it disappears, it could be a sign of crash. It could also disappear after RE-INVITE, though

Answer (score 0):

The UAS has the responsibility to terminate the Session for the other UAC [Egress] if it detects that the UAC [Ingress] is not responding or vice versa.

The Session timers define periodic health checks to make sure that the call is alive on both ends of the call. Usually during the signaling negotiation the UAC / UAS can specific who is going to perform the Session checks and at what intervals.  So based on the UAS being the Refresher - Lack of Response can trigger it to terminate the other session. And if its a refresh receiver then the lack of request after a particular interval can force its hand to close the session. But in this case the detection of failure is based on the interval time of the refresh.

Other mechanisms are detecting the RTP stream if the UAS is still part of the media between the end points. There are RTP inactivity mechanisms that can be used for this that could determine when its loss of end point and not just hold or silence on the line.

The use of Transport oriented protocols can help alleviate the issue if the calls have unique connection and its loss can be immediate trigger at the UAS to take corrective action.